# form not saving email in django admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

django forms doesn't save email in the database.i try all sort of things but still it is the only thing that is not saving .I need help
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNBTW.png

```
forms.py
         from django import forms
         from django.contrib.auth.models import User
         from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


        class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
             email=forms.EmailField()

        class meta:
       model=User
          fields=    ['username', 'email_address', 'password1','password2']



views.py code
    register(request):
 if request.method=='POST':
    form=UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        username=form.cleaned_data['username']
        password1=form.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2=form.cleaned_data['password2']
        email_address=form.cleaned_data['email']
        form.save()

        return redirect('/')
else:

    form=UserRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'blog/register.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: In the class definition you have `email_address` in the field list, but in the form processing, you refer to `cleaned_data['email']`.  Which is it?  `email` or `email_address`?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the field is `email`, *not* <s>`email_address`</s>. You thus should change this to:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

Furthermore `password1` and `pasword2` are no model fields either. The `UserCreationForm` has some logic to compare the fields, and set a password.

In your `register` view, there is no need to unpack the cleaned data, you can just use `form.save()`. You can call `login(request, user)` if you want to automatically login the user you just created:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/register.html',{'form':form})
```

You can override the `UserAdmin` admin with:

```
# blog/admin.py

from blog.forms import UserRegistrationForm

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.unregister(User)

@admin.register(User)
class NewUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form_template = 'blog/register.html'
    add_form = UserRegistrationForm
```

Comment: **@Willem Van Onsem **I try it but still when I entered the admin section I only see the username .the email address field is still empty.

Comment: @MustaphaMohdSagagi: that is logical. In the admin section, you will need to define a `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: **@Willem Van Onsem **thanks. but please can you show me how

Comment: **@Willem Van Onsem **object has no attribute User admin

Comment: @MustaphaMohdSagagi: that was a typo :)

Comment: **@Willem Van Onsem ** still it didn't work. Take a look at the image at the top (see edit).you will see Amira but the email address won't show.

Answer (score 0):

In django documentation the class used in UserCreationForm is Meta. you have to use capital M for meta class.You should get it correct when you have changed to capital M

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email']
```